# Kendo chart setting y axis to integer numeric value

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I am using Telerik Kendo Chart and i try to show integer values to y axis. 
here is no problem when my values like 6 - 8 - 10 but for example when i use the code which is below, i get values on y axis like that:

My y axis chart values(8 and 9)

I get,

7.4
7.6 
7.8
8.0
...
...
9.0

But i want to set values to y axis integer values like 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 etc. How can i do it? I mean how can i show integer values on my y axis?

Here is my code:

```
               @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
               .Name("chart")
               .Title(title => title
                .Text(@ViewBag.a)
               .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top))

               .Legend(legend => legend
               .Visible(true)
               .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top))
               .Series(series =>
               {
                   series
                   .Column(model => model.a, categoryExpression: model => model.date).Name("name")
                   .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Count)
                    .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true).Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.Center));
                   series
                   .Column(model => model.b, categoryExpression: model => model.date).Name("name")
                   .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Count)
                    .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true).Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.Center));


               })
                    .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDB"))



               .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
               .Date()
               .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Years)
               .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))

               )



               .Theme("metro")
               .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
               .Visible(true)
              .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")))
```

When i use this code:

```
 .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:n0}"))),
```

I get y axis values like that:

7 
8 
8 
8 
8 
8 
8 
9 
9 
9 
9 
9 
9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding Major Unit in the Value Axis Of the Chart. Please see the below code that you need to append:

```
.ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                       .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:n0}"))
                       .MajorUnit(1))
```